# Pass custom values to each iteration of iterator in `for..of` loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, iterable

Say we have a custom iterable like so:

```
class MyIterable {

  val = 1;

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      next: () => {
        return {
          done: this.val > 3,
          value: this.val++
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

for(const v of new MyIterable()){
  console.log(v);
}
```

my **first** question is - is there a way to pass a new value to the next() method each time? Something like this:

```
class MyIterable {

  val = 1;

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      next: (a,b,c) => {  // pass a,b,c
        return {
          done: this.val > a,
          value: this.val + b + c
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then somehow passing `a,b,c` using `for..of`:

```
let [a, b, c] = [...];
for(const v of new MyIterable(), [a,b,c]){ // bogus syntax
  console.log(v);
  a = 5; //
}
```

this actually has some use-case:

1. break out of iteration early, with some smarter internally defined condition?
2. filter results

However, we could accomplish these things in other ways, so certainly not that useful.

So my **second** question is - is this about as good as it's going to get in terms of iterating and passing custom values:

```
   const generate = function*(iterator: Iterator<any>, a, b, c) {
    
      while(1){
        const {done,value} = iterator.next.apply(iterator,[a,b,c]);
        if(done){
          return;
        }
        yield value;
      }
    
    };
```

which would be used like so:

```
for(const v of generate(new MyIterable()[Symbol.iterator](), 3,4,5)){
  console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: You can use class constructor

Comment: sure but that won't change by iteration easily

Comment: @AlexanderMills I feel like [iterator helpers](//github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) can help here somehow, but I’m still unsure what exactly you’re trying to do. Note that [`next`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol) is intended to take at most _one_ argument. This corresponds to the single return value of the [`yield`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) operator. Wouldn’t a generator method make this a bit easier?

Comment: @SebastianSimon maybe my answer will help understand, the question is more academic than practical

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but don't do this:

```
class MyIterable {

  val = 1;

  iterator(v: any){

    const self = this;

    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]() {

        return {
          next: () => {
            const {a,b,c} = v; // get new ref to abc if they change
            return {
              done: self.val > a,
              value: this.val = this.val + b + c
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

const z = {a: 3, b: 4, c: 5}
for(const v of new MyIterable().iterator(z)){
  z.a = 4;
  console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: Seems you've more or less done the same thing as I did here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446609/how-to-pass-value-to-iterator.  Though in your case, since `next()` can take a value, you could probably reimplement this as a generator function and do something like `a = yield return { done, value }`, rather than going through the ctor.  Though at that point, you would have to call `next(a)` manually, rather than the `for` calling `next()` automatically.  Guess it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Tradeoffs.  Always tradeoffs.

Comment: that's cool, if you want to add your own answer then I will upvote your answer bc it makes sense thanks