# How to Pass Value to Iterator

Tags: c#, iterator, generator, coroutine

In JavaScript, we have the `yield` operator, which is able to return a value optionally provided to the generator via the `next()` method.  From [next](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next#parameters):

> ## Parameters
>
> `value` Optional
> The value to send to the generator.
>
> The value will be assigned as a result of a `yield` expression. For example, in `variable = yield expression`, the value passed to the `.next()` function will be assigned to `variable`.

And [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#return_value):

> ## Return value
>
> Returns the optional value passed to the generator's `next()` method to resume its execution.

In C#, I understand the rough equivalent to `Generator.prototype.next()` is [`IEnumerator.MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext).  However, whereas `next()` takes the optional `value` parameter, it does not appear there is any equivalent parameter in `MoveNext()`.

I'd really like some way of being able to pass a value to a C# iterator like I can pass a value to a JavaScript generator.  I suppose I could maybe try using channels etc., but I was hoping to take advantage of the syntactic sugar C#'s own `yield` operator provides.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: A [C# Iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) is not a Generator. [`IEnumerator.MoveNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=net-7.0) doesn't accept a parameter. You won't be able to change the sequence within the `MoveNext()` call, if that is what you are trying to do. You can create an iterator method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: You are correct, similar but not the same.  I'm trying to see if there are any workarounds for the fact that `MoveNext` doesn't take any arguments.  Maybe there isn't any and I just have to accept the fact that the C# syntax I'd like doesn't currently exist.  In that case I'd like to know what's the alternative.  Maybe I do just need to get familiar with channels...

Comment: Maybe I should have included this in the question proper, but if you want some more context for what I am wanting to be able to do, you can check out the "Example Usage" of redux-saga here:  https://redux-saga.js.org/

Comment: I don't see a `next(arg)` call in the example but I assume the important part is the user ID API call 'side effect'.

Comment: @JonathanDodds right, that happens in the redux-saga middleware library.  The saga generator function in the example `yield`s a `call` effect to redux-saga, which performs the call and uses `next(result)` to hand the response back to the generator.

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74906826/pass-custom-values-to-each-iteration-of-iterator-in-for-of-loop

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after fiddling around with this some, here is a rough beginning to an answer.  It's loosely based on [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield).

```cs
namespace Coroutine
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var point = new Point(1, 2, 3);
            foreach (var coordinate in point)
            {
                Console.Write(coordinate);
                Console.Write(" ");

                point.Arg = coordinate;
            }
            // Output: 1 3 6
        }

        public class Point
        {
            public Point(int X, int Y, int Z)
            {
                this.X = X;
                this.Y = Y;
                this.Z = Z;
                this.Arg = 0;
            }

            public int X { get; }
            public int Y { get; }
            public int Z { get; }
            public object Arg { get; set; }

            public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
            {
                yield return X + (int)Arg;
                yield return Y + (int)Arg;
                yield return Z + (int)Arg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bit ugly, but I imagine after some cleaning up this could maybe work.

Basically in lieu of calling `move(value)`, I'm setting `Arg` before the `foreach` calls `MoveNext()`.  In lieu of `variable = yield expression;`, I have `yield expression; variable = Arg;`.

The main point of the test is to verify I can, in fact, pass data into the iterator, e.g. modify the iterator's behavior, from the outside caller.  This approach still makes some use of the `foreach/yield` syntax, i.e. does not manually recreate the iterator's state machine generated by the compiler.

Hope this is useful for anyone with the same question, and happy to hear any other ideas you might have.  I imagine I'd clean this up before making actual production use of it, maybe add some utility methods and template types, but for now it's a simple test that gets at the main idea.